# Protovis and JqPlot performance

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, jqplot, protovis

I am evaluating the Protovis and Jqplot javascript visualization toolkits. I found both are good. But I want to know their performance while plotting huge number of data points say 1,00,000 to 10,00,000. Please share your experience which is performance wise best between above? in terms of speed and accuracy.

Thanks,
Omky

Answer (score 1):

I have only recently started using protovis (on Chrome).  I was plotting streamgraphs with 10 timepoints per layer, 10000 layers, and it could take 5-10 min of compute time to render.  I don't know if it will handle simple "scatter" plot more efficiently.  I am not familiar with the other plotting library.